# Sum all numbers in each line and add an average of them to the end of line Bash

Tags: bash

The task is: using awk command sum all numbers in each line and add average to the end of each line. It is not necessary that each line has same amount of numbers. Example:

```
Steven 1 2 3 4 5 
Mark 2 3 4 
Joe 3 5 5 6
```

so the result should be

```
Steven 1 2 3 4 5 3
Mark 2 3 4 3
Joe 3 5 5 6 5
```

I can't quite figure out how to sum numbers in line with awk and how to add average to the end of line since lines' length can be different. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{ sum = 0;
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
           sum += $i
       $(++NF) = int (sum / (NF - 1) + 0.5)
     } 1' file
```

- `int (sum / (NF - 1) + 0.5)` rounds the average to nearest integer,
- `1` at the end means print every line after processing.

Above command yields:

```
Steven 1 2 3 4 5 3
Mark 2 3 4 3
Joe 3 5 5 6 5
```

Comment: I agree with this. Good job.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks a lot. Do you mind answering two questions? First is what 1 closing } does and second is if there is a way to sum all averages and calculate the average of all averages? Like sum of averages/number of lines? Thanks!

Comment: @oguzismail nvm, I did it myself :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Mak, read the [tag:awk] "learn more" page to see what `1` does.

Answer (score 1):

perl works nicely here:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -MPOSIX=round -lane '
    push @F, round(sum(@F[1..$#F]) / (@F - 1)) if @F > 1;
    print "@F"
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk '{ sum = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {sum += $i ;}   print $0, sum/(NF-1)}' a.txt
```

The output is

```
Steven 1 2 3 4 5 3 3
Mark 2 3 4 3 3
Joe 3 5 5 7 5 5
```